# How to add additional settings to Black formatter in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, formatter

I just added the Black formatter to pycharm, and am trying to tweak the settings a bit on how the formatting should go. I'm working with a partner who uses vscode, and these are the settings he uses in which I'm trying to duplicate on pycharm:

```
"python.formatting.blackArgs": [
    "--line-length",
    "160",
    "--skip-string-normalization"
],
```

Here is the current config I have set up: [image]

Answer (score 1):

Add it in Arguments.

```
"$FilePath$" --line-length 160
```

[image: PyCharm External Tool Settings]